# UBUNTU 13.10 installation problem

Tags: dual-boot

i have installed ubuntu 13.10 in my windows 7 pc , but iam not getting a dual boot option 
at start.the pc automatically boots into windows 7 os without prompting dual boot.
please tell me what to do?.

Comment: try boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

During boot up, press and hold the SHIFT key to make the operating system choices appear. Later, this can be changed inside Windows to let Ubuntu appear first.